# the bash expression $"usage {break|continue}"

Tags: bash

I have seen a expression `$"usage {break|continue}"`,what is the difference between `"usage {break|continue}"` and `$"usage {break|continue}"`,both of them got same result.

```
echo $"usage {break|continue}"
usage {break|continue}
echo "usage {break|continue}"
usage {break|continue}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dollar double quoting is an extremely rarely used form of [quoting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) to deal with internationalization. From `man bash`:

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign ($"string") will cause the string to be translated according to the current locale.  If the current locale is C or  POSIX, the  dollar  sign is ignored.  If the string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.